# When we connect my registration form in SQL Server in cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); line error will occur

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I get this error:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '-'.
> Incorrect syntax near '-'.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Regisation_Form
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-7FCU1CM\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=RegistationFormData; Integrated Security=True";
            con.Open();
        }

        protected void Unnamed12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistationFormDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into RegistationForm" + "(First-Name, Last-Name, Mobile-No, Date Of Birth, E-mail, Address,Pincode,State,Country, Gender,Password) values(@First-Name,@Last-Name,@Mobile-no,@Date Of Birth,@E-mail,@Address,@pincode,@Gender, @State,@Country, @Password)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First-Name", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last-Name", TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile-no", TextBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date Of Birth", TextBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@E-Mail", TextBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBox6.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pincode", TextBox7.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", TextBox8.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", TextBox9.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", DropDownList1 .SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox10.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You query is full of ambiguous statements. Starting from the reserved word First, Last etc and also using “-”.  The “-” is interpreted as maths operator without “[“ ”]”.

Answer (score 2):

The problem are the "-" in the names of the columns and the parameters. These are not valid identifiers. SQL thinks `First-Name` is something named `First` minus something else named `Name`. Either change them to something like `FirstName` or escape them like `[First-Name]`.

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO RegistationForm ([First-Name], [Last-Name], ...) " +
    "VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, ...)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", TextBox2.Text);
```

In any case you can easily change the parameter names. Whether you also want to change the column names in the table is up to you.